# Python: SQL Alchemy query, update

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

уважаемое комьюнити. Сложилась следующая проблема.
У меня в распоряжении есть БД, с таблицей, у которая подобная структура:

<kbd>`id`</kbd>    <kbd>`name`</kbd>    <kbd>`page_orientation_id`</kbd>

<kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`for_test`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`2`</kbd>     <kbd>`for_test`</kbd><kbd>`1`</kbd>

Мне нужен  метод, который при своем вызове по id, изменял бы page_orientation, в текущем случае с 1 на 2 и в обратной последовательности.

Я взял SQL Alchemy и набросал вот такой метод:

```
def change_orientation(self, message_body):
    default_orientation = self.__get_default_orientation()
    if default_orientation == 1:
       page_orientation = self.db_session.query(
            TableName
        ).filter(
            TableName.id == message_body['id']
        ).update(TableName.page_orientation_id + 1)
        return {
            'page_orientation': page_orientation
        }
    else:
        _page_orientation = default_orientation
        return {
            'page_orientation': _page_orientation
        }
```

Но он не работает, так как нужно.

Поскольку в SQL Alchemy я очень  недавно, как и в работе с транзакциями,буду благодарен за помощь в решении, или за информацию касательно направления для изучения вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача решается по примерам из самого начала вводной страницы документации по Алхимии [Object Relational Tutorial — SQLAlchemy 1.2 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)

"Подготовительные" работы:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    page_orientation_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.page_orientation_id = 1

    def switch_orientation(self):
        self.page_orientation_id = 2 if self.page_orientation_id == 1 else 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Test(id={self.id}, name={self.name}, orientation={self.page_orientation_id})>'


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Работа с объектом:

```
session = Session()
test = Test('for_test')  # объект создан, но в базе отсутвует <Test(id=None, name=for_test, orientation=1)>
session.add(test)
session.commit()  # объект записан в базу, установлен id <Test(id=1, name=for_test, orientation=1)>

id = test.id  # сохраняем для будущего запроса
del test      # и удаляем объект для чистоты эксперимента

session = Session()
test = session.query(Test).filter_by(id=id).one()  # объект загружен из базы <Test(id=1, name=for_test, orientation=1)>
test.switch_orientation()  # изменена ориентация <Test(id=1, name=for_test, orientation=2)>
session.commit()  # в базе новое значение поля ориентации
```

если бы устроили значения 0 и 1, то код можно еще немного упростить:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.page_orientation_id = False

def switch_orientation(self):
    self.page_orientation_id = not self.page_orientation_id
```

Comment: Благодарю. Появилось понимание.